# Possible to browse objects in google stackdriver logger?

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

When logging a massive js object from google apps script into the google cloud platforms stackdriver logger, i'd like to browse the object rather than seeing a massive stringified obj text string.

Is that possible to achieve with google stackdriver logging?

Comment: Stackdriver will not beautify your JSON string. You can download the logs and format as you desire or write a program. Tip: I would not use Stackdriver to log massive objects. I would instead write the object to Cloud Storage as formatted text and send the URL to Stackdriver logs.

Comment: How are you logging the value? Note there is a limit on the size of the log. In general, avoid stringification by logging the object as an object property: `console.log({ myobj: myobj });`

Comment: tehhowch: just like you supposed!

Comment: ok, seems there is no real possipility for that